# renderer.isWebGLAvailable is not a function at filename.html

Tags: javascript, netbeans, three.js, webgl

So I think i could solve my link problem so far, but now i still have an uncaught TypError: rendere.isWEBglAvailable is not a function at filname.html
So what do i have to implement to get it work?

```
 <title>3D Montageanalysetool</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        <script src="Libraries/three.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Libraries/OrbitControls.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Libraries/OBJLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Libraries/MTLLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- ZURBFundation links-->
        <link href="ZURBFundation/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="ZURBFundation/js/vendor/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>





     <script>
                //Detctor shows a warning if the current browser do not support WebGL.
                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                if (renderer.isWebGLAvailable()===true) {
                    // Initiate function or other initializations here
                    animate();
                } else {
                    var warning = renderer.getWebGLErrorMessage();
                    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(warning);
                }

</script>
```

Comment: Is your `src` looking in the correct location? You are currently looking at the location of the current file.

Comment: help me please!! i need it for school

Comment: We can't help you if you don't comment/respond to our comments/questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to go down the order of your `<script>` tags, and see what each one of them is doing.

- First you have `<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` but we don't know what that file is doing. Does this file expect for three.js to be already loaded? If so, you need to move it down the order so `index.js` is loaded **after** Three is available.
- Second, you're trying to import the Three.js library from `threejs-viewer-master/lib/threejs/three.js` but have you checked that it's the right address? Does your console or network tab show that this asset is being loaded?
- Third, you're loading a **duplicate** three.js lib from `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js` This is probably polluting your library code and rendering it unusable. You should also load a newer revision, `/r100/` instead of `/r79/` at this point.

This is not a Three.js issue, it's a script order issue, with a possibility of linking to non-existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you mention Three.js first.

```
    <title>3D Montageanalysetool</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="threejs-viewer-master/lib/threejs/three.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- links to create a new anchor-->
<script src="threejs-viewer-master/lib/threejs/Detector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="threejs-viewer-master/lib/threejs/MTLLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="threejs-viewer-master/lib/threejs/OBJLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="threejs-viewer-master/lib/threejs/OrbitControls.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- ZURBFundation links-->
<link href="ZURBF
```

undation/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="upperDiv">
            <h1 id="varhead">3D-Montageanalysetool</h1>

            <div id="buttonsDiv" >
                <!-- Button to get send a request to the server and get the coordinates as answer and draws them-->
                <button id="butLoad" class = "secondary button" onclick="onButtonLadeClick" >Lade Daten</button>
                <!-- Button to set the AvarageHigh visible form the server-->
                <button id="setAvarageHighVisible"  class="button secondary"  onclick=""> Durchschnittshöhe anzeigen</button>
                <!-- Button to show reach of anchor-->
                <button id="anchorReach" class="button secondary" onclick="">Reichweite Anchor   
                </button> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--show Fullscreen-->
    <div id="fullscreen">
        <a id="fullscr"> Fullscreen</a>
    </div>
    <!--canvas div-->
    <div id="drawingSpace" align="center" > </div>
    <!--show no Fullscreen-->
    <div id="noFullscreen">
        <a id="noFullscr">No Fullscreen</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        //Detctor shows a warning if the current browser do not support WebGL.
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        if (renderer.isWebGLAvailable()) {
            // Initiate function or other initializations here
            animate();
        } else {
            var warning = renderer.getWebGLErrorMessage();
            document.getElementById('container').appendChild(warning);
        }



        //renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        render();
        function render() {
            //Renderer -> because till jet nothing is rendered onto the canvas
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        }
        animate();

        function animate() {
            //show in browser
            requestAnimationFrame(animate); //browser has to request the function animate
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }



            render();


        }

    </script>
</body>
```